# Filter json file with tickboxes in Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter results from my JSON file so the user can click on ladies or mens 'styles', but some products have both a ladies and mens styles, so how would I be able to show the results for 'both' without having three tick boxes?  I know I cannot have duplicate names in my JSON, but have done this just as an example for now. Any help would be appreciated. I have put my code here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fXOZHqo48ntvsdJA875y?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(prop, ignoredValue) in { 'category': true, 'cut': true }" ng-init="filter[prop]={}">
        <b>{{prop | capitalizeFirst}}:</b><br />
        <span class="quarter" ng-repeat="opt in getOptionsFor(prop)">
            <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[prop][opt]" />&nbsp;{{opt}}</b>
        </span>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="w in filtered=(products | filter:filterByProperties)">
        {{w.name}} ({{w.category}})
    </div>
    <hr />
    Number of results: {{filtered.length}}
</div>
```

Comment: you can not have properties with same name inside same object like you have `"cut": "ladies",
    "cut": "mens",` , you should rewrite your logic to have array there..

Comment: Hi, yes but this is where I am stuck, as I do not know how to write this to have the option of the two styles and then filter from there.

Comment: let me check in few minutes..and will let you know..

Comment: Took my lot of time but finally I did it..take a look at plunkr and added answer.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make couple of changes in your json.

1. Whenever there is `cut` has one value then it would be `string` & whenever there is more than one value then you could maintain an `array`
   like `"cut": "ladies"`, `"cut": "mens",` & `"cut": ["ladies","mens"]`
2. You need to handle string and filter thing in your `filterByProperties` function

**Markup**

```
<span ng-show="!isArray(opt)" class="quarter" ng-repeat="opt in getOptionsFor(prop)">
    <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[prop][opt]" />&nbsp;{{opt}}</b>
</span>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.isArray = function(val) {
    return angular.isArray(val)
}

$scope.filterByProperties = function(product) {
    // Use this snippet for matching with AND
    var matchesAND = true;
    for (var prop in $scope.filter) {
      if (noSubFilter($scope.filter[prop])) continue;
      if (!$scope.isArray(product[prop])) { //if its not an array
        if (!$scope.filter[prop][product[prop]]) {
          matchesAND = false;
          break;
        }
      } else {
        //if its an array
        for (var i = 0; i < product[prop].length; i++) {
          var anyPropMatch = false;
          if ($scope.filter[prop][product[prop][i]]) {
            anyPropMatch = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!anyPropMatch) {
          matchesAND = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return matchesAND;
};
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Awb8oQK3PgOQT6BQ4MTZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)